# Steam: Downloaded game in Windows—want to play in Ubuntu

Tags: games, steam

I recently purchased Borderlands 2 on Steam, and installed it in Windows. Currently, my Windows is installed alongside Ubuntu (my primary OS). I was not aware that Borderlands 2 could be run on Ubuntu, and would like to play it there.

Is there a way of moving the Windows files to a Ubuntu directory? Even if all the files won't work, are there some chunks I can get away with moving—then doing something like "verify game files" to patch up w/e else is needed?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just copy installed files from Program files and start playing with wine. It wont work, wine will not be able to load all files and play.
I try this on NFS:most wanted and counter strike 1.6. since these games of less size and graphics and didnt play well, new games of bigger size will also have same problem.

If you can install the game using setup with [PlayonLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/) you may be able to play it. *what I mean is, you have to install the game again in ubuntu using playonlinux.*

Steam on the other hand is installable on linux since valve have made it available so

Comment: Ever since you asked this, Borderlands 2 has become available for Linux under Steam.  If you haven't already done so, I would just re-install it on Ubuntu if you so desire.